# Regular expressions for password validation missing work

Tags: validation, passwords, expression

I need to validate a password that matches the following criteria:

- Must be at least 6 characters long (?=.{6})
- String contains a numbers(0-9) and least 1 uppercase letter(A-Z) and least 1 (-) character.
- String not start and end with a - character (invalid : -ABCDE or ABCDE- etc..)

**valid Strings**

A-BCDE

ABC-DE

1B-CDE

1-BCDE

AB-CD1

ABCD-1

my regex

^.*(?=.{6})(?=.*\d)(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[-]).*$

demo url :

http://www.rubular.com/r/YHdPCjSW6P

**invalid strings**

ABCDEF (No - character must be one of at least 1 -)

-ABCDE (- the first character can not be)

ABCDE- (- the last character can not be)

A-BC-D (- can not be more than 1)

Answer (score 1):

Would that work for you ?

```
^.*(?=.{6})(?=[^\-].*[a-zA-Z])[a-zA-Z0-9\-]{1,5}[^\-]$
```

See example here http://www.rubular.com/r/spfqXIVZyX

Comment: Thanks tchap
But 

some problems

A-B-DE (invalid because - 2 used times)

- only used 1 times and least 1 (-) character all times.

and

ABCDEF (invalid because - not used)


look at pls

http://www.rubular.com/r/qXCubwnmM0

Answer (score 0):

valid Strings

A-BCDE

ABC-DE

1B-CDE

1-BCDE

AB-CD1

ABCD-1

invalid strings

ABCDEF (No - character must be one of at least 1 -)

-ABCDE (- the first character can not be)

ABCDE- (- the last character can not be)

A-BC-D (- can not be more than 1)

my regex now

^.*(?=.{6})(?=[^-].*[a-zA-Z])[a-zA-Z0-9-]{1,5}[^-]$

demo url :

http://www.rubular.com/r/3Q6Ozs4aVB